# How do I make this HTML Print Screen code a simple button instead of text?

Tags: html, button, printscreen

```
<a title="Print Screen" alt="Print Screen" onclick="window.print();"    target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer;">CLICK HERE TO PRINT FORM!</a>
```

Comment: You can use css to change the look also choose to use <button> element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the [button tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp) :

```
<button onclick="window.print();">CLICK HERE TO PRINT FORM!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a hyper link. You need to use a button instead.

```
<input type="button" name="Print Screen" value = "CLICK HERE TO PRINT FORM!" onclick="window.print();"    target="_blank" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a button you have to use the button tag instead of `<a/>` ( `<button />` )

Comment: Just so you know you can use a ` symbol to make this answer clearer or use four spaces as this is code. As is, the `a` can be confused to not mean the `<a>` html tag

Answer (score 0):

Something you may not want to hear is that I would possibly prefer this to be a hyperlink since it navigates to a new tab and utilizes the target="_blank"

This link has a guide to when to use a button or a hyperlink near the middle of the article. http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/

mayankTUM beat me to the next part of my answer which he was faster at writing. This would be a more proper solution per your request by using `<input type="button" />`. His syntax works and fulfills your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use recently.  The (.5) means 50% if you leave it as () it is 100%

```
<a button onclick=window.print(.5) class="btn"> print </a>
```